# Click dropdown of different page

Tags: reactjs

I don't know how can I click the dropdown of another page for button I know I can do this page.click('button[id="loginbox"]'), but I want for dropdown by classname.i have one hover dropdown whose html is
 which opens dropdown window whose html is  this contains another dropdown dropdown menu

whose value I want to add in list and send to my prevous page. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("classname") [0].click()`

But this is a bad approach, as multiple elements can exist with classes. That is why id's used for such behaviour, so only one specific element is being clicked at a time.

But without code examples, that is best answer I can provide.